# using spring data jpa with spring boot issue

Tags: jdbc, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

**my entity Client**

```
@Entity
public class Client implements Serializable {
@Id @GeneratedValue
private long code;
private  String nom;
private  String email;
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "client",fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Collection<Compte> comptes;
public Client(long code, String nom, String email, Collection<Compte> comptes) {
    this.code = code;
    this.nom = nom;
    this.email = email;
    this.comptes = comptes;
}
/...
getters and setters
}
```

**entity Compte**

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "TYPE_CPTE,",discriminatorType= DiscriminatorType.STRING,length = 2)
public abstract class Compte implements Serializable {
@Id
private String codeCompte;
private Date dataCreation;
private  double solde;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="CODE_CLI")
private  Client client;
@OneToMany(mappedBy="compte")
private Collection<Operation> operations;

public Compte() {
    super();
}

      public Compte(String codeCompte, Date dataCreation, double solde, Client          client, Collection<Operation> operations) {
       this.codeCompte = codeCompte;
       this.dataCreation = dataCreation;
       this.solde = solde;
       this.client = client;
       this.operations = operations;
       }

    /...
   getters and setters
  }
```

**entity Operation**

```
   @Entity
   @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
   @DiscriminatorColumn(name = "TYPE_OP",discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING,length = 1)
   public abstract class Operation implements Serializable{
   @Id @GeneratedValue
   private long numero;
   private Date dateOperation;
   private double montant;
   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "CODE_CPTE")
   private Compte compte;

   public Operation() {
    super();
    }

   public Operation(Date dateOperation, double montant, Compte compte) {
    this.dateOperation = dateOperation;
    this.montant = montant;
    this.compte = compte;
   }
  /...getters and setters 
  }
```

**entity Retirer**

```
  @Entity
  @DiscriminatorValue("R")
  public class Retrait extends Operation {
  public Retrait() {
  }
  public Retrait(Date dateOperation, double montant, Compte compte) {
    super(dateOperation, montant, compte);
  }
  }
```

**entity versement**

```
  @Entity
  @DiscriminatorValue("V")
  public class Versement extends Operation {
  public Versement() {
  }
  public Versement(Date dateOperation, double montant, Compte compte) {
    super(dateOperation, montant, compte);
  }
  }
```

**entity Comptecourant**

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("CE")
public class CompteEpargne extends Compte {
private double taux;
public CompteEpargne(String s, Date date, int i, Client c2, double taux) {
    this.taux = taux;
}

public CompteEpargne(String codeCompte, Date dataCreation, double solde, Client client, Collection<Operation> operations, double taux) {
    super(codeCompte, dataCreation, solde, client, operations);
    this.taux = taux;
}
public CompteEpargne(){
    super();
}
/...getters and setters 
}
**entity CompteEpagne**

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("CC")
public class CompteCourant extends Compte {
private  double decouvert;

public CompteCourant(String s, Date date, int i, Client c1, double decouvert) {
    this.decouvert = decouvert;
}

public CompteCourant(String codeCompte, Date dataCreation, double solde, Client client, Collection<Operation> operations, double decouvert) {
    super(codeCompte, dataCreation, solde, client, operations);
    this.decouvert = decouvert;
}
public  CompteCourant(){
    super();
}
/...getters and setters 
}
```

**Repositorys**
**1**

```
@Repository
public interface ClientRep extends JpaRepository<Client,Long> {
}
```

**2**

```
@Repository
public interface CompteRep extends JpaRepository<Compte,String> {
}
```

**3**

```
@Repository
public interface OperationRep extends JpaRepository<Operation,Long> {
@Query("select o from Operation o where o.compte.codeCompte=:x order by o.dateOperation desc ")
public Page<Operation> listOperation(String codeCpte, Pageable pageable);
}
```

**service**

```
public interface IBankMetier  {
public Compte consulterCompte(String codeCpte);
public void verser(String codeCpte, double montant);
public void retirer(String codeCpte, double montant);
public void virement(String codeCpte1, String codeCpte2, double montant);
public Page<Operation> listOperation(String codeCpte, int page, int size);
}
```

**implimantation**

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class BankMetierImp implements IBankMetier {
@Autowired
private CompteRep compteRep;
@Autowired
private OperationRep operationRep;
@Override
public Compte consulterCompte(String codeCpte) {
    Compte cp = compteRep.findOne(codeCpte);
    if (cp == null) throw new RuntimeException("Compte introvable");
    return cp;
}

@Override
public void verser(String codeCpte, double montant) {
    Compte cp = consulterCompte(codeCpte);
    Versement v = new Versement(new Date(), montant, cp);
    operationRep.save(v);
    cp.setSolde((cp.getSolde() + montant));
    compteRep.save(cp);
}

@Override
public void retirer(String codeCpte, double montant) {
    Compte cp = consulterCompte(codeCpte);
    double facili = 0;
    if (cp instanceof CompteCourant)
        facili = ((CompteCourant) cp).getDecouvert();
    if (cp.getSolde() + facili < montant)
        throw new RuntimeException("solde insuffisant");
    Retrait retrait = new Retrait(new Date(), montant, cp);
    operationRep.save(retrait);
    cp.setSolde((cp.getSolde() - montant));
    compteRep.save(cp);
}

@Override
public void virement(String codeCpte1, String codeCpte2, double montant) {
    retirer(codeCpte1, montant);
    verser(codeCpte2, montant);
}

@Override
public Page<Operation> listOperation(String codeCpte, int page, int size) {
    return operationRep.listOperation(codeCpte,new PageRequest(page,size));
}
}
```

**Spring boot Application**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MeinproApplication implements CommandLineRunner {
@Autowired
private ClientRep clientRep;
@Autowired
private CompteRep compteRep;
@Autowired
private OperationRep operationRep;
@Autowired
BankMetierImp bankMetier;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(MeinproApplication.class, args);

}
  @Override
  public void run(String... strings) throws Exception {
    Client c1=clientRep.save(new Client("martin","martin@gmail.com"));
    Client c2=clientRep.save(new Client("john","john@gmail.com"));

    Compte cp1=compteRep.save(new CompteCourant("c1",new Date(),9000,c1,6000));
    Compte cp2=compteRep.save(new CompteEpargne("c2",new Date(),63000,c2,12220));

    operationRep.save(new Retrait(new Date(),6000,cp1));
    operationRep.save(new Retrait(new Date(),10000,cp2));
    operationRep.save(new Versement(new Date(),2000,cp1));
    operationRep.save(new Versement(new Date(),20,cp2));
    bankMetier.verser("c1",1000);
    bankMetier.virement("c1","c2",2000);

}
}
```

**application.properties**

```
# DataSource settings:
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/monbank
spring.datasource.username=roo
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop          
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

**when I run it booom !!!!**

```
2017-02-12 16:15:24.858  INFO 6232 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.0.11.Final}
2017-02-12 16:15:24.860  INFO 6232 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2017-02-12 16:15:24.863  INFO 6232 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
2017-02-12 16:15:24.947  INFO 6232 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
2017-02-12 16:15:25.113  INFO 6232 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
2017-02-12 16:15:25.938  INFO 6232 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.tuple.PojoInstantiator     : HHH000182: No default (no-argument) constructor for class: meinpro.entiti.Client (class must be instantiated by Interceptor)
2017-02-12 16:15:26.209  INFO 6232 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000227: Running hbm2ddl schema export
Hibernate: alter table compte drop foreign key FK2hw4shqsxc782lychpkr52lmv
2017-02-12 16:15:26.228 ERROR 6232 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table compte drop foreign key FK2hw4shqsxc782lychpkr52lmv
2017-02-12 16:15:26.228 ERROR 6232 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : Table 'monbank.compte' doesn't exist
Hibernate: alter table operation drop foreign key FKkr9nfjf0ipqrw5xwcf9jqq6gv
2017-02-12 16:15:26.229 ERROR 6232 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table operation drop foreign key FKkr9nfjf0ipqrw5xwcf9jqq6gv
2017-02-12 16:15:26.229 ERROR 6232 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : Table 'monbank.operation' doesn't exist
Hibernate: drop table if exists client
Hibernate: drop table if exists compte
Hibernate: drop table if exists operation
Hibernate: create table client (code bigint not null auto_increment, email varchar(255), nom varchar(255), primary key (code))
Hibernate: create table compte (type_cpte, varchar(2) not null, code_compte varchar(255) not null, data_creation datetime, solde double precision not null, decouvert double precision, taux double precision, code_cli bigint, primary key (code_compte))
2017-02-12 16:15:26.712 ERROR 6232 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000389: Unsuccessful: create table compte (type_cpte, varchar(2) not null, code_compte varchar(255) not null, data_creation datetime, solde double precision not null, decouvert double precision, taux double precision, code_cli bigint, primary key (code_compte))
2017-02-12 16:15:26.713 ERROR 6232 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ' varchar(2) not null, code_compte varchar(255) not null, data_creation datetime,' at line 1
Hibernate: create table operation (type_op varchar(1) not null, numero bigint not null auto_increment, date_operation datetime, montant double precision not null, code_cpte varchar(255), primary key (numero))
Hibernate: alter table compte add constraint FK2hw4shqsxc782lychpkr52lmv foreign key (code_cli) references client (code)
2017-02-12 16:15:27.146 ERROR 6232 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table compte add constraint FK2hw4shqsxc782lychpkr52lmv foreign key (code_cli) references client (code)
2017-02-12 16:15:27.147 ERROR 6232 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : Table 'monbank.compte' doesn't exist
Hibernate: alter table operation add constraint FKkr9nfjf0ipqrw5xwcf9jqq6gv foreign key (code_cpte) references compte (code_compte)
2017-02-12 16:15:27.330 ERROR 6232 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table operation add constraint FKkr9nfjf0ipqrw5xwcf9jqq6gv foreign key (code_cpte) references compte (code_compte)
2017-02-12 16:15:27.331 ERROR 6232 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : Can't create table `monbank`.`#sql-23d4_77` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")
2017-02-12 16:15:27.332  INFO 6232 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000230: Schema export complete
2017-02-12 16:15:27.414  INFO 6232 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2017-02-12 16:15:27.938  INFO 6232 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.h.i.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator  : HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
2017-02-12 16:15:28.776  INFO 6232 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@2ffb82a2: startup date [Sun Feb 12 16:15:18 PST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-02-12 16:15:28.936  INFO 6232 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2017-02-12 16:15:28.938  INFO 6232 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2017-02-12 16:15:29.022  INFO 6232 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-02-12 16:15:29.022  INFO 6232 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-02-12 16:15:29.112  INFO 6232 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-02-12 16:15:29.263  WARN 6232 --- [  restartedMain] .t.AbstractTemplateResolverConfiguration : Cannot find template location: classpath:/templates/ (please add some templates or check your Thymeleaf configuration)
2017-02-12 16:15:30.063  INFO 6232 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2017-02-12 16:15:30.159  INFO 6232 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2017-02-12 16:15:30.246  INFO 6232 --- [  restartedMain] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http)
Hibernate: insert into client (email, nom) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into client (email, nom) values (?, ?)
2017-02-12 16:15:30.461  INFO 6232 --- [  restartedMain] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2017-02-12 16:15:30.472 ERROR 6232 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:779) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:760) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.afterRefresh(SpringApplication.java:747) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at meinpro.MeinproApplication.main(MeinproApplication.java:30) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save(): meinpro.entiti.Compte; nested exception is org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save(): meinpro.entiti.Compte
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:333) ~[spring-orm-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:244) ~[spring-orm-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:491) ~[spring-orm-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59) ~[spring-tx-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213) ~[spring-tx-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147) ~[spring-tx-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:133) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:57) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213) ~[spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy86.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at meinpro.MeinproApplication.run(MeinproApplication.java:38) [classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:776) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    ... 11 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save(): meinpro.entiti.Compte
    at org.hibernate.id.Assigned.generate(Assigned.java:34) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:101) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.core.JpaPersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(JpaPersistEventListener.java:67) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:189) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:132) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:58) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:775) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:748) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:753) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1146) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:298) ~[spring-orm-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy82.persist(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:508) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:504) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:489) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:461) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:61) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282) ~[spring-tx-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136) ~[spring-tx-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    ... 22 common frames omitted

2017-02-12 16:15:30.478  INFO 6232 --- [  restartedMain] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@2ffb82a2: startup date [Sun Feb 12 16:15:18 PST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-02-12 16:15:30.483  INFO 6232 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
2017-02-12 16:15:30.485  INFO 6232 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2017-02-12 16:15:30.485  INFO 6232 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000227: Running hbm2ddl schema export
Hibernate: alter table compte drop foreign key FK2hw4shqsxc782lychpkr52lmv
2017-02-12 16:15:30.488 ERROR 6232 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table compte drop foreign key FK2hw4shqsxc782lychpkr52lmv
2017-02-12 16:15:30.489 ERROR 6232 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : Table 'monbank.compte' doesn't exist
Hibernate: alter table operation drop foreign key FKkr9nfjf0ipqrw5xwcf9jqq6gv
2017-02-12 16:15:30.499 ERROR 6232 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table operation drop foreign key FKkr9nfjf0ipqrw5xwcf9jqq6gv
2017-02-12 16:15:30.500 ERROR 6232 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : Can't DROP 'FKkr9nfjf0ipqrw5xwcf9jqq6gv'; check that column/key exists
Hibernate: drop table if exists client
      Hibernate: drop table if exists compte
      Hibernate: drop table if exists operation
      2017-02-12 16:15:30.879  INFO 6232 --- [  restartedMain]            org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000230: Schema export complete
      Process finished with exit code 0
```

**please help me**

Comment: Please explain your problem, if you are having any with the code and log you have provided here. Only code doesn't explains anything.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is telling you exactly what the problem is

> Caused by: org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save(): meinpro.entiti.Compte

The id in your `Compte` class is not a generated value, like the other tables

```
@Id
private String codeCompte;
```

So you need to set this value yourself before you save it.

Now look at the `CompteEpargne` and the `CompteCourant` (which extend `Compte`) constructors

```
public CompteEpargne(String s, Date date, int i, Client c2, double taux) {
    this.taux = taux;
}

public CompteEpargne(String codeCompte, Date dataCreation, double solde, Client client, Collection<Operation> operations, double taux) {
    super(codeCompte, dataCreation, solde, client, operations);
    this.taux = taux;
}

public CompteCourant(String s, Date date, int i, Client c1, double decouvert) {
    this.decouvert = decouvert;
}

public CompteCourant(String codeCompte, Date dataCreation, double solde, Client client, Collection<Operation> operations, double decouvert) {
    super(codeCompte, dataCreation, solde, client, operations);
    this.decouvert = decouvert;
}
```

The first constructor of each type only sets one value, while the second calls the super constructor, which set *all* the values (id included). When you are saving, you are using the first constructor

```
Compte cp1=compteRep.save(new CompteCourant("c1",new Date(),9000,c1,6000));
Compte cp2=compteRep.save(new CompteEpargne("c2",new Date(),63000,c2,12220));
```

You are calling the constructor that only sets one value. So you probably need to fix how that those constructors are setting properties. Maybe you want to do something like

```
public CompteEpargne(String s, Date date, int i, Client c2, double taux) {
    this(s, date, i, c2, new ArrayList<Operation>(), taux);
}
```

where you call the other constructor.

Answer (score 0):

**Simple Solution**

1. Your id attribute is not set. This may be due to the fact that the DB field is not set to auto increment.
2. For MySQL (as you have given in Properties file) use this below sample for defining your POJO class.

   ```
   @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) @Column(name="id",   unique=true, nullable=false) public Long getId() { return this.id; }
   ```

Comment: where can I it implement ??

Answer (score 0):

thanks friends the problem is in the class Compte

```
 @DiscriminatorColumn(name = "TYPE_CPTE,",discriminatorType= DiscriminatorType.STRING,length = 2)
```

with in the name is =**"TYPE_CPTE,"** hhhh I dont see the comma after TYPE_CPTE

```
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "TYPE_CPTE",discriminatorType= DiscriminatorType.STRING,length = 2)
```